# Why do people down vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

I don't understand why people give down vote to a question even though it may not be stupid. Some don't even specify the reason for down vote. Are they doing this intentionally to reduces other's reputation? Stack Overflow should provide a facility that we can see who gave us a down vote.

Comment: -1 for not using capital letters properly

Comment: -1 for not using question mark.

Comment: I don't think that is important...I think that should not make difference...If I write my query in small letter or capital meaning of word would be same...

Comment: Concrete example is better than saying "not stupid question", since even good question that is not stupid, but seems off-topic (or other reasons that are already stated on tour/help) is **not** good for the site.

Comment: @Jamal why you people waste your time by checking all these things?

Comment: If you have a specific question in mind, please share the link so we can verify if the question is appropriate for the site.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre: You have no idea how many times this same discussion has been brought up.

Comment: @Azik: But he did use the question mark: "are they do this intentionally to reduces others no. of reputation?"

Comment: "Stack Overflow should provide a facility that we can see who gave us a down vote" - that would be a one way ticket to retaliation war. It's good to keep things as cold and focused as possible.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre *why you people waste your time by checking all these things?* that is the way the community is here on SO. Accept it, live it and get great help. If you don't like it, you are free to look for another community that better fits your style.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre, more down votes to your SO posts after this question posted. Don't worry about reputations which can be earned easily. But take serious about down votes by improving your questions to get needed answers. StackOverflow is the best site for me to get and give programming help.

Comment: A useful resource for you may be [John Skeets: Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) to vote is a valuable privilege we have on Stack, and in most societies.  It allows us all to decide the value of a comment or a question.

There are several reasons why you may have gotten a down-vote.  Generally if it is egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

You can post a comment to your question asking the down-voter to give you feedback as to why they down-voted you.  Personally i try to always leave a comment stating why i down-voted someone in-order to help them improve there posting in the future.

By the way this question will probably be closed soon as a duplicate. You didn't bother to check that there are probably 5 other questions already on meta stack that answer it.  That's why i down-voted your question here.

Answer (score 10):

The use of this site is free. But you need to follow the rules. And it is your task to make the question as clear as possible.

I checked your question, and I agree it is not perfectly clear. But if you reply a downvote with a rude comment, don't be surprised if you won't get any answer at all.

Answer (score 7):

A guideline is given in the tooltip of the downvote button:

[image]

I higlighted the reason I would downvote your question for. And I don't need to give a reason, **everyone is free to vote as he likes to**.
<sub>except unfair serial downvoting</sub>

Comment: +1 for line-breaking freehand circle

Comment: i have gone through all previous post but i didn't get answer..i don't know how solve this problem...I am here to ask for your help but if you give me only down vote then how would I get what is my mistake?

Comment: @MohiniMhetre, [Voting is different here on meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @MohiniMhetre Right now the site is helping you to work on your shaky technical writing and communication skills. These are valuable life skills, so you should take advantage of the help.